# Identifying Records Where a String Appears More Than Once

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a following dataset that looks like:

```
 ID    Medication         Dose
 1          Aspirin        4
 1          Tylenol        7
 1          Aspirin        2   
 1          Ibuprofen      1
 2          Aspirin        6
 2          Aspirin        2
 2          Ibuprofen      6
 2          Tylenol        4
 3          Tylenol        3
 3          Tylenol        7
 3          Tylenol        2
```

I would like to develop a code that would identify patients who have been administered a medication more than once. So for example, ID 1 had Aspirin twice, ID 2 had Aspirin twice and ID 3 had Tylenol three times.

I could be wrong but I think the easiest way to do this would be to concatenate each ID based on Medication using a code similar to the one below; but I'm not quite sure what to do after that - is it possible to count if a string appears twice within a cell?

```
 SELECT DISTINCT ST2.[ID],
     SUBSTRING(
         (
             SELECT ','+ST1.Medication AS [text()]
             FROM ED_NOTES_MASTER ST1
             WHERE ST1.[ID] = ST2.[ID] 
              Order BY [ID] 
        FOR XML PATH ('')
         ), 1, 200000) [Result]
    FROM ED_NOTES_MASTER  ST2
```

I would like the output to look like the following:

```
 ID MEDICATION                    Aspirin2x   Tylenol2x     Ibuprofen2x  
 1  Aspirin, Tylenol , Aspirin         YES       NO             NO
 2  Ibuprofen, Aspirin, Aspirin        YES       NO             NO           
 3  Tylenol, Tylenol ,Tylenol          NO        YES            NO
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: You are struggling here because that is not how relational data works. You are going to need dynamic sql here to generate these columns. Then you need to use aggregation to count each string before you munge them together into a single tuple. Search this site for "dynamic pivot". There are dozens and dozens of examples of how to generate your columns. The additional piece of aggregation to count values is not difficult from there.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen 2012

Answer (score 3):

For the first part of your question (identify patients that have had a particular medication more than once), you can do this using GROUP BY to group by the ID and medication, and then using COUNT to get how many times each medication was given to each patient. For example:

```
SELECT ID, Medication, COUNT(*) AS amount
FROM ST2
GROUP BY ID, Medication
```

This will give you a list of all ID - Medication combinations that appear in the table and a count of how many times each combo appears. To limit these results down to just those that are greater than 2, you can add a condition to the COUNTed field using HAVING:

```
SELECT ID, Medication, COUNT(*) AS amount
FROM ST2
GROUP BY ID, Medication
HAVING amount >= 2
```

The problem now is formatting the results in the way you want. What you will get from the query above is a list of all patient - medication combinations that came up in the table more than once, like this:

```
ID    |   Medication  | Count
------+---------------+-------
1     | Aspirin       | 2
2     | Aspirin       | 2
3     | Tylenol       | 3
```

I'd suggest that you try and work with this format if possible, because as you have found, to get multiple values returned in a comma delimited list as you have in your Medication column you have to resort to some hacks to get it to work (although a recent version of SQL Server does implement some sort of proper group concatenation functionality.). If you really need the Aspirin2x etc. columns, [take a look at the PIVOT operation in SQL Server.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: While this may be helpful, it does not generate the output expected by the OP.

Comment: Check Stuff - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 for formatting of string, just in case if it helps.

Comment: This solves the first part of OP's question (identifying repeat patient-med combinations). For the 2nd part (how to _display_ the results), I think OP should handle that on the client side, rather than directly in SQL.